# Excel Formula Implementation in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to implement a logic in my R script for the below shown sample data frame.  `df`

```
   ID    A            B
    1  2.471264262    0
    2  2.53024575     0
    3   2.559114933   1
    4  2.502350493    1
    5  2.529496526    0
    6  2.480199137    0
    7  2.521066835    0
    8  2.481272625    0
    9  2.505953959    0
    10 2.481272625    0
    11 2.499424723    0
    12 2.492515087    0
    13 2.502385996    0
    14 2.487579633    0
    15 2.479438021   -1
    16 2.044195946    1
    17 2.054051421    0
    18 2.108811073    1
    19 2.249767599    0
    20 2.627294516   -1
    21 2.624337386    0
    22 2.157110862    0
    23 2.142325212   -1
    24 2.124582433   -1
    25 2.114725333    0
    26 2.113739623    0
    27 1.92054047     0
    28 2.00037188     0
    29 2.183995509    0
    30 2.629451192    0
    31 2.772756046    0
    32 2.603141474    0
    33 2.502385996    0
```

`Column B` shows the data point where State is changed. Now I need to implement a complex logic where I will be adding or subtracting the `"Correction Factor"` for the values in `Column A` for next 15 data points from the point where `B == 1 or -1`.

The formula for the correction factor is as follows,

If `B == 1` then `Correction Factor == [A - 0.19*(15/15)*A]`, Also value the fraction (15/15) will keep on decrementing for the next 15 values like (14/15) , (13/15) .....(0/15).

Similarly if `B == -1` then `Correction Factor == [A + 0.53*(15/15)*A]`, Also value (15/15) will keep on decrementing for the next 15 values like (14/15) , (13/15) .....(0/15).

And another condition to consider is that, Once a state change has be detected in `B` then though there is state change with in the next 15 values, it should not be considered. Ex First change in state is detected at B3 then though there is state change in B4,B15,16 it should not be considered.

For a better Understanding I have attached my expected output along with the formulas executed manually in excel.

**Expected Output**

```
    A               B           A With Correction Factor         Formula Executed  
    2.471264262     0              2.471264262             Same Value of A retained since no transition
    2.53024575      0              2.53024575              Same Value of A retained since no transition
     2.559114933    1              2.072883096             A4-0.19* (15/15)*A4
     2.502350493    1              2.058600339             A5-0.19* (14/15)*A5
     2.529496526    0              2.112972765             A6-0.19* (13/15)*A6
     2.480199137    0              2.103208868             A7-0.19* (12/15)*A7
     2.521066835    0              2.169798189             A8-0.19* (11/15)*A8
     2.481272625    0               2.166978093            A9-0.19* (10/15)*A9
     2.505953959    0              2.220275208             A10-0.19* (9/15)*A10
     2.481272625    0              2.229836999             A11-0.19* (8/15)*A11
     2.499424723    0              2.277809064             A12-0.19* (7/15)*A12
     2.492515087    0               2.30308394             A13-0.19* (6/15)*A13
     2.502385996    0               2.34390155             A14-0.19* (5/15)*A14
     2.487579633    0              2.361542265             A15-0.19* (4/15)*A15
     2.479438021    -1             2.385219376             A16-0.19* (3/15)*A16
     2.044195946    1               1.992409649            A17-0.19* (2/15)*A17
     2.054051421    0               2.028033436            A18-0.19* (1/15)*A18
     2.108811073    1               2.108811073            A19-0.19* (0/15)*A19
      2.249767599     0             2.249767599           Same Value of A retained since no transition
     2.627294516     -1             4.019760609            A21+0.53*(15/15)*A21
     2.624337386     0               3.922509613            A22+0.53*(14/15)*A22
     2.157110862     0              3.147943785             A23+0.53*(13/15)*A23
     2.142325212    -1              3.050671102             A24+0.53*(12/15)*A24
    2.124582433     -1              2.950336805              A25+0.53*(11/15)*A25
    2.114725333      0              2.861928284             A26+0.53*(10/15)*A26
     2.113739623     0              2.785908823             A27+0.53*(9/15)*A27
     1.92054047      0               2.463413243            A28+0.53*(8/15)*A28
     2.00037188      0              2.495130525             A29+0.53*(7/15)*A29
     2.183995509     0               2.647002557            A30+0.53*(6/15)*A30
     2.629451192     0               3.093987569            A31+0.53*(5/15)*A31 
     2.772756046    0                3.164638901            A32+0.53*(4/15)*A32
    2.603141474     0                 2.87907447            A33+0.53*(3/15)*A33
    2.502385996      0               2.679221273            A34+0.53*(2/15)*A34
```

**Edit**
The code suggested below works exactly as required for the above mentioned dataframe i.e the dataframe with 33 rows, but I have the below data frame with 32rows and code doesnt work. Any suggestion on this?

```
    ID    A               B
    1  2.471264262    0
    2  2.53024575     0
    3   2.559114933   1
    4  2.502350493    1
    5  2.529496526    0
    6  2.480199137    0
    7  2.521066835    0
    8  2.481272625    0
    9  2.505953959    0
    10 2.481272625    0
    11 2.499424723    0
    12 2.492515087    0
    13 2.502385996    0
    14 2.487579633    0
    15 2.479438021   -1
    16 2.044195946    1
    17 2.054051421    0
    18 2.108811073    1
    19 2.249767599    0
    20 2.627294516   -1
    21 2.624337386    0
    22 2.157110862    0
    23 2.142325212   -1
    24 2.124582433   -1
    25 2.114725333    0
    26 2.113739623    0
    27 1.92054047     0
    28 2.00037188     0
    29 2.183995509    0
    30 2.629451192    0
    31 2.772756046    0
    32 2.603141474    0
```

Well I was not able to post another question giving this post as the reference so I have updated iin the same post.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, the counting to 15 is a little tricky, so we use a `for` loop to calculate the correct counter and state. The actual formula is then relatively simple:

```
counter <- 0
current_state <- NA
for (i in seq_along(df$B)) {
  if (counter == 0) {
    if (df$B[i] == 0) next
    counter <- 15
    current_state <- df$B[i]
    df$state[i] <- df$B[i]
    df$counter[i] <- counter
  } else {
    counter <- counter - 1
    df$state[i] <- current_state
    df$counter[i] <- counter
  }
}

df$A_corr <- ifelse(df$state == 1, 
                    df$A - 0.19 * (df$counter / 15) * df$A,
                    df$A + 0.53 * (df$counter / 15) * df$A)
df$A_corr <- ifelse(is.na(df$A_corr), df$A, df$A_corr)
```

Gives:

> ```
> > df
>    ID        A  B state counter   A_corr
> 1   1 2.471264  0    NA      NA 2.471264
> 2   2 2.530246  0    NA      NA 2.530246
> 3   3 2.559115  1     1      15 2.072883
> 4   4 2.502350  1     1      14 2.058600
> 5   5 2.529497  0     1      13 2.112973
> 6   6 2.480199  0     1      12 2.103209
> 7   7 2.521067  0     1      11 2.169798
> 8   8 2.481273  0     1      10 2.166978
> 9   9 2.505954  0     1       9 2.220275
> 10 10 2.481273  0     1       8 2.229837
> 11 11 2.499425  0     1       7 2.277809
> 12 12 2.492515  0     1       6 2.303084
> 13 13 2.502386  0     1       5 2.343902
> 14 14 2.487580  0     1       4 2.361542
> 15 15 2.479438 -1     1       3 2.385219
> 16 16 2.044196  1     1       2 1.992410
> 17 17 2.054051  0     1       1 2.028033
> 18 18 2.108811  1     1       0 2.108811
> 19 19 2.249768  0    NA      NA 2.249768
> 20 20 2.627295 -1    -1      15 4.019761
> 21 21 2.624337  0    -1      14 3.922510
> 22 22 2.157111  0    -1      13 3.147944
> 23 23 2.142325 -1    -1      12 3.050671
> 24 24 2.124582 -1    -1      11 2.950337
> 25 25 2.114725  0    -1      10 2.861928
> 26 26 2.113740  0    -1       9 2.785909
> 27 27 1.920540  0    -1       8 2.463413
> 28 28 2.000372  0    -1       7 2.495131
> 29 29 2.183996  0    -1       6 2.647003
> 30 30 2.629451  0    -1       5 3.093988
> 31 31 2.772756  0    -1       4 3.164639
> 32 32 2.603141  0    -1       3 2.879074
> 33 33 2.502386  0    -1       2 2.679221
> ```

Comment: I am getting a new error which says `Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "state", value = c(NA, NA, NA, NA,  : 
  replacement has 306 rows, data has 513789`,  may I know the reason for this? My input data is around 51K.

Comment: Can't tell since the code here works fine. You'll need a reproducible example to illustrate your problem and ask a new question (possibly linking this one).

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error. The Issue is there is  33 rows in the above mentioned data set and the code works fine with data set of 33 rows, by deleting one single row or adding one row the code fails. Any solution to this?

Comment: Sounds like a naming issue, make sure you are the correct object names. Maybe start in a clean session.

Comment: Nope Not naming issue, did you try the same dataframe by deleting one data i.e having only 32 rows.? I also tried restarting the session. But couldnt find a possible solution.

Comment: @SBS Error Might be because of the `for` loop, replace the for loop in the above code with the code referred here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45726959/implementing-sequential-counter-of-decreasing-values-in-r  , and later replace the formula execution part with the code given here. Hope this helps.