# Implementing sequential counter of decreasing values

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to implement a counter that decrements `dec_cnt`by 1 based on certain conditions.

Below is my dataframe `df`.

```
 ID   A
  1   0
  2   0
  3   0
  4   1
  5   1
  6   0
  7   0
  8   0
  9   0
10    0
11    0
12    0
13    0
14    0
15    0
16   -1
17    1
18    0
19    1
20    0
21   -1
22    0
23    0
24   -1
25    0
26    0
27    0
28    0
29    0
30    0
31    0
32    0
33    0
34    0
```

The conditions are
a. The counter should start from the data point where the `A==1 or -1` and start decrementing the counter for next `16` values,for example value of `A == 1` at `ID 4`, so from `ID == 4` till `ID==19` the decrement counter should be implemented starting from value `15` till counter is `0`. Also to note that if there exists any `A== 1/-1`  in between this range it should be ignored.
b. I also need to implement `retain_A` column which retains the value of `A` through out the `counter`.

Below is my expected output.

```
 ID   A       retain_A   dec_cnt
  1   0         NA         NA
  2   0         NA         NA
  3   0         NA         NA
  4   1         1          15
  5   1         1          14
  6   0         1          13
  7   0         1          12
  8   0         1          11
  9   0         1          10
10    0         1          9
11    0         1          8 
12    0         1          7
13    0         1          6
14    0         1          5
15    0         1          4
16   -1         1          3
17    1         1          2
18    0         1          1
19    1         1          0          
20    0         NA         NA
21   -1         -1         15
22    0         -1         14
23    0         -1         13
24   -1         -1         12
25    0         -1         11
26    0         -1         10
27    0         -1          9
28    0         -1          8
29    0         -1          7
30    0         -1          6
31    0         -1          5
32    0         -1          4
33    0         -1          3
34    0         -1          2
```

The similar kind of question had been posted couple of days ago where the solution uses `for loop`, Also the `loop` fails to execute if the data points are more than `35`. I wanted to avoid `for loop` because its execution time will be more if we are dealing with huge amount of data.

The data frame is take from the question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45670637/excel-formula-implementation-in-r)

below is the script that I tried using the above referenced post.

```
  dec_cnt <- 0
  Retain_A <- NA
  for (i in seq_along(df$A)) {
    if (dec_cnt == 0) {
      if (df$A[i] == 0) next
     dec_cnt <- 15
     Retain_A <- df$A[i]
     df$Retain_A[i] <- df$A[i]
    df$dec_cnt[i] <- dec_cnt
   } else {
    dec_cnt <- dec_cnt - 1
    df$Retain_A[i] <- Retain_A
    df$dec_cnt[i] <- dec_cnt
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just find all first `1` and `-1`s, subset 16 rows after it and add a sequence (and `1`/`-1`)? Can you provide your example in an easy to paste form, like `dput()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's realistic to avoid any kind of loop, `for` or otherwise. Perhaps a more realistic goal would be to avoid loops that iterate over every single value, regardless of whether it is relevant.

Starting from your 2-column input, let's pre-set the empty columns:

```
dat$retain_A <- NA
dat$dec_cnt  <- NA
```

Here's where we can gain some efficiency: instead of repeatedly making comparisons, we can *know* if it matches -1/1 now:

```
ind <- which(dat$A %in% c(-1,1))
last_match <- 0
ind
# [1]  4  5 16 17 19 21 24
```

The trick is to keep track of the `last_match` and discard any indices between it and the next 15 entries.

```
ind <- ind[ind > last_match]
while (length(ind) > 0) {
  i <- seq(ind[1], min(ind[1] + 15, nrow(dat)))
  dat$dec_cnt[i] <- head(15:0, n = length(i))
  dat$retain_A[i] <- dat$A[ ind[1] ]
  last_match <- ind[1] + 15
  ind <- ind[ind > last_match]
}
dat
#    ID  A retain_A dec_cnt
# 1   1  0       NA      NA
# 2   2  0       NA      NA
# 3   3  0       NA      NA
# 4   4  1        1      15
# 5   5  1        1      14
# 6   6  0        1      13
# 7   7  0        1      12
# 8   8  0        1      11
# 9   9  0        1      10
# 10 10  0        1       9
# 11 11  0        1       8
# 12 12  0        1       7
# 13 13  0        1       6
# 14 14  0        1       5
# 15 15  0        1       4
# 16 16 -1        1       3
# 17 17  1        1       2
# 18 18  0        1       1
# 19 19  1        1       0
# 20 20  0       NA      NA
# 21 21 -1       -1      15
# 22 22  0       -1      14
# 23 23  0       -1      13
# 24 24 -1       -1      12
# 25 25  0       -1      11
# 26 26  0       -1      10
# 27 27  0       -1       9
# 28 28  0       -1       8
# 29 29  0       -1       7
# 30 30  0       -1       6
# 31 31  0       -1       5
# 32 32  0       -1       4
# 33 33  0       -1       3
# 34 34  0       -1       2
```

You'll find that your initial loop iterates once per row whereas this solution iterates only once per non-zero.